# How to fix Filebeat permission denied error while initializing harvesting logs

Tags: ubuntu, docker, file-permissions, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have ELK docker container having ports open and Filebeat on separate container. I am getting Logstash index and Filebeat index in Kibana dashboard. Some logs are being sent to Elastic Search using Logstach from Filebeat. The logs folder for my application from which I am trying to get logs running outside the Filebeat container and it is mapped inside the Filebeat container. All the containers are on same network. But when Filebeat comes to read my application logs I am getting premission denied error. I have tried to read separate apache logs as well but getting same error for reading logs. I am doing all this on Vagrant host with Oracle Virtual Box.

Can anybody tell me how i can give permissions or add user to my application or any other way to do that?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker and docker-compose and using ELK 5.6.3.

Following are the logs:

```
filebeat_1  | 2017/10/18 09:12:42.390679 prospector_log.go:271: ERR Harvester could not be started on existing file: /na
sir/default/logs/kern.log, Err: Error setting up harvester: Harvester setup failed. Unexpected file opening error: Faile
d opening /nasir/default/logs/kern.log: open /nasir/default/logs/kern.log: permission denied

filebeat_1  | 2017/10/18 09:12:42.391278 prospector_log.go:271: ERR Harvester could not be started on existing file: /na
sir/default/logs/auth.log, Err: Error setting up harvester: Harvester setup failed. Unexpected file opening error: Faile
d opening /nasir/default/logs/auth.log: open /nasir/default/logs/auth.log: permission denied

filebeat_1  | 2017/10/18 09:12:52.394579 prospector_log.go:271: ERR Harvester could not be started on existing file: /na
sir/default/logs/auth.log, Err: Error setting up harvester: Harvester setup failed. Unexpected file opening error: Faile
d opening /nasir/default/logs/auth.log: open /nasir/default/logs/auth.log: permission denied

filebeat_1  | 2017/10/18 09:12:52.395299 prospector_log.go:271: ERR Harvester could not be started on existing file: /na
sir/default/logs/kern.log, Err: Error setting up harvester: Harvester setup failed. Unexpected file opening error: Faile
d opening /nasir/default/logs/kern.log: open /nasir/default/logs/kern.log: permission denied
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the files you are trying to process?

Comment: There was a lock on the files which i was trying to access. I resolved it by adding filebeat as sudo user to get the logs.